# How can I make a gameobject snap to something when it gets close to it?

Tags: unity

Any idea if there is a way I can make a gameobject snap to something when it gets close to it? Like drag a cube around and when it gets close to something then snap to it.

Comment: I upvoted it to counter the downvote, because I tried searching, and it took a while to find anything, as snapping defaults to result for snapping in the scene editor, after about 5 or 6 tries, I still only found weak unclear references.

Answer (score 2):

Any position you want it to snap to as it gets close, you could do something like this (Psuedo code)

(assuming you already have code to move the object)
 - Create a parent object, that contains the script SnapOn.
 - That parent object is what moves.
 - The child object should have the visible element, cube for instance.
 - In the SnapOn Script, 
 - - The anchors are used to define positions the object can snap to
 - - The "movable" is the child object that actually renders.
 - - SnapDistance is how far away to snap.

```
class SnapOn {
public Transform[] anchors;
public Transform movable;
public float SnapDistance = 1f;

Update() {
  // first we find the closest object, but looping through all and saving the shortest distance (and position)
  var distance = float.max;
  var point = vector3.zero;
  foreach(var anchor in anchors)
  {
    var d = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, anchor.position);
    if (d < distance) 
    {
      distance = d;
      point = anchor.position;
    }
  }

  // now we decide if there is anything it should snap to.
  if (distance > SnapDistance) // too far, keep renderable with movable.
  {
    movable.position = transform.position;
  }
  else // position is close enough to snap point put it there.
  {
    movable.position = point;
  }
}
```

if you neglect to track the moving position separate from where to render the object, the instance you are on a snap on to a position, you will unlikely be able to move the object far enough in a single frame to allow it to "unsnap"